# How to hide section title in Asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I've searched, but I can't find a way to hide the section title on the main page, and to only display in the `Table of Contents` (:toc:). As seen from this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7gMp.png), `Home` and `Test` are external links to the adoc files. I want to only keep it in the `Table of Contents`.

I know it's possible to hide section title in the `Table of Contents` by using [discrete] keyword, but is it possible to do the other way around?

Here is the adoc file of this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7gMp.png):

```
:toc: left
:source-highlighter: highlight.js
:toclevels: 3
:sectlinks:

== <<Home.adoc#, Home>>

== <<Test.adoc#, Test>>

== Title 1

=== Title 1.1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you made the section title a document title (a single equal sign) then you could hide it by adding the `notitle` document attribute.

```
= Document Title
:notitle:
:toc:

== Section A

== Section B
```

There's no way currently to hide a regular section title.